# An error occurred while parsing the page - Python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a g2g.com page with `bs4`. But nothing works for me. There must be an error somewhere in the code. What can be the reason? Thanks in advance!

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = "https://www.g2g.com/offer-11677180/Amnennar-TBC--FR----Alliance?service_id=lgc_service_1&brand_id=lgc_game_29076&region_id=ac3f85c1-7562-437e-b125-e89576b9a38e&sort=lowest_price&attributes=%257B%2522lgc_29076_server%2522%253A%255B%2522lgc_29076_server_40957%2522%255D%257D&online=online"
response = requests.get(link)
with open(path + str(fileName) + ".html", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
with open(path + str(fileName) + ".html", "r") as f:
    html = f.read()
with open(path + str(fileName) + ".html", "w") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    blockList = soup.find("div", {"id": "pre_checkout_sls_offer"})
    for i in blockList:
        block = blockList.find_all("div", {"class": "other_offer-desk-main-box other_offer-div-box"})
        for j in block:
            insideBlock = block.find_all("div", {"class": "flex-1 align-self"})
            for k in insideBlock:
                seller = insideBlock.find("div", class_="seller__name-detail")
                stock = insideBlock.find("div", class_="offers-bottom-attributes offer__content-lower-items")("span") # str(stock)[7:-8]
                price = insideBlock.find("span", class_="offer-price-amount")
                print(seller, stock, price)
```

Comment: Please tell us what didn't work, including any errors you got, and what output you expect.

Comment: @JanWilamowski I want to get a string with information about a product. One page shows 20 results. But the problem is that it only shows one 20 times to me.

Comment: That's an excellent question, Just one small thing, you've to [edit] your question and include your expected output and the current output to make it easier for both of us!

Comment: @jodaje9131 [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You are just dealing with `JavaScript` website, `requests` library will not be able to render `JS` for you. Therefore, you've to use a real browser automation such as selenium.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def main(driver):
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.g2g.com/offer-11677180/Amnennar-TBC--FR----Alliance?service_id=lgc_service_1&brand_id=lgc_game_29076&region_id=ac3f85c1-7562-437e-b125-e89576b9a38e&sort=lowest_price&attributes=%257B%2522lgc_29076_server%2522%253A%255B%2522lgc_29076_server_40957%2522%255D%257D&online=online")

        elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.CLASS_NAME, "other_offer-desk-main-box.other_offer-div-box"))
        )

        goal = [(x.find_element_by_class_name("seller__name-detail").text,
                 x.find_elements_by_class_name(
                     "offers-bottom-attributes.offer__content-lower-items")[1].text,
                 x.find_element_by_class_name("offer-price-amount").text)
                for x in elements]
        return pd.DataFrame(goal, columns=["Seller", "Stock", "Price"])

    except TimeoutException:
        return "Unable to find desired information"

    finally:
        driver.quit()
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    print(main(driver))
```

Output:

```
          Seller      Stock     Price
0      g2aseller      2,800  0.022841
1       kevinlei      3,000  0.022849
2           Eyse  3,318,614  0.023107
3   Meteorkasper        950   0.02313
4   fortwonasell      2,000   0.02315
5      VegoStore    195,780    0.0232
6         Thanku  4,959,200  0.023407
7     AlotofGold  7,807,751  0.023407
8       speedVIP  5,612,958   0.02344
9           Aeda    150,000   0.02376
10    HellenWong  9,786,442  0.023807
11          Good  9,252,414     0.024
12      BestGold    305,880     0.024
13         Happy  9,994,699     0.024
14   Moonbootica      1,150  0.024032
15     byefriend     37,030    0.0241
16          baby    714,645   0.02413
17         jaina  1,215,220   0.02419
18      yang9732     28,888    0.0242
19       SunRise  9,860,048  0.024228
```